# Converting the value in a text into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file that looks like this.

```
Paul Velma 63.00
Mcgee Kibo 71.00
Underwood Louis 62.75
Clemons Phyllis 57.50
```

I am trying to make them into a dictionary but I got stuck because I am not sure how to slice them into keys and values. Below is my code.

```py
dt_stu=[]
infile = open("C:\\Users\kwokw\Downloads\\student_avg.txt",'r')
for line in infile:
    key,value=line.split([0:9])
    dt_stu[key]=value
print(dt_stu)
```

Comment: What should be the key and what should be the value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsplit()` with `maxsplit=1` for convenient line splitting

```
dt_stu={}
for line in infile:
    key, value = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    dt_stu[key] = value
```

```
{'Paul Velma': '63.00', 'Mcgee Kibo': '71.00', 'Underwood Louis': '62.75', 'Clemons Phyllis': '57.50'}
```

Answer (score 1):

**str.rsplit()** lets you specify how many times to split

```
s = "a,b,c,d"
s.rsplit(',', 1)
```

Output: `['a,b,c', 'd']`

I edited your code try this:

```
dt_stu={}
infile = open("draft.txt",'r')
for line in infile:
    key,value = line.rsplit(' ', 1)
    dt_stu[key]=float(value.strip())
print(dt_stu)
```

Output: `{'Paul Velma': 63.0, 'Mcgee Kibo': 71.0, 'Underwood Louis': 62.75, 'Clemons Phyllis': 57.5}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the .split method of strings to split on the spacebar, i.e. `my_string.split(" ")`. Then iterate through that list.

Comment: I am using the split method, but I don't know how to split the first name and last name as a key, and the grade as the values

Comment: When you use .split you will get a list, e.g. `["Paul", "Velma", "63.00"]`. The first two elements of the list are your key, the third is the value

Comment: but it gives me a valueerror saying too many values to unpack (expected 2) when I try this.